# FindAndModify using Couchbase

Tags: couchbase

I have a collection of documents that need to be processed by multiple client nodes.
Basically, each document should be processed by only 1 client node.

So what I'm thinking of is creating a unique clientId for each node and set the clientId to the document being processed to tell other clients that this document is being processed.

I already implemented this approach using Mongodb a couple of years ago by using the **findAndModify** operator which guarantees the **atomicity of both setting the clientId to the document and returning it**.
Now I'm looking for a maybe similar approach in Couchbase but couldn't find.

Any idea on how to do it?

Comment: Which language are you coding with?

Comment: Java (I'm using java-sdk-3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are searching for is the method called **getAndLock**. It will guarantee that only one server is reading this document.

Updating the document with an attribute might be a bad idea if the server fails during this process, as no other server will take over those documents that have already have been assigned to the faulty one.

Answer (score 1):

We have handeled similar kind of scenario in our project. What we do is to create one document and save other processing doc in that. If that document is not present in that, then it you can prevent it getting updated by other client.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you explain maybe by a small example of the documents you are mentioning?